# How to get back to windows after install Ubuntu in the same partition?

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, windows, backup

I have two partition on my system. On one partition, I keep my data, and on other I install my OS.

By mistake, I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on the drive I had installed Windows. Now I need to get back to windows, but I don't want to loose my data.

Is there any method by which I can do that without using another hard drive ?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: I installed ubuntu by using a pendrive. Here's how I made the bootable:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

And then I by mistake installed it on my OS partition

Comment: No, what I meant did you choose along side windows, or replace windows?

Comment: I replaced windows.

Comment: Well... Windows is gone, but if your data is on the other drive, it should be fine.  You'll have to reinstall windows.

Comment: That's fine. I have a windows CD through which I can install windows. But when I tried to install, I didn't saw any partition on which I have installed ubuntu.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8042/discussion-between-mitch-and-addresseerajat)

Comment: @Mitch: Sorry to bother you again, but I followed the instructions. It removed ubuntu from my system. The only problem is, I don't see the partition on which I have installed my ubuntu, as that's the same drive on which I want to install Windows. My guess is that the problem is related to different formats of drives.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Boot from the windows CD or DVD, and you will be able to create a partition.

Comment: Let me tell you the problem I am facing.
I have a 250 gb HDD. I had created a 35 gb partition for installing OS, and the rest for data. When I try to boot from Windows DVD, I only see the other drive (which I use for storing my stuff) and I don't want to disturb that.

Comment: @Mitch: Thank you very much for your patience. I later figured out that while installing ubuntu, I had somehow deleted that partition as well, and that's the reason I was confused. 
Anyways, I re-installed windows, and for the time being, will be using VM to work on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

If you've formatted the windows drive, you're stuck.You can use your windows disc (or get an image file using your key, from the microsoft website) to reinstall windows on that partition, but as of now, you can recover some data using testdisk or photorec, but you can't restore the whole drive into it's previous state.

If you didn't format the disk, get BOOTITNG online(http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/bootit-next-generation.htm).  There is a free version available. Use it to restor MBR to Win7 MBR. It has an option to do it directly. You need to make a bootable disk/pen drive using another pc though.

Comment: You should elaborate what you chose while installing ubuntu.

Comment: OK. And can you help me how to get access my data in the other partition. The format of that partition was NTFS, and I don't know how to access that data.

Comment: I replaced windows while installing ubuntu

Comment: You can just use ubuntu to access that now can't you? :D

FYI - You don't see the ubuntu partition while installing windows because windows doesn't detect ext4 and swap partitions. Because windows is crap :D. If you wanna reinstall windows just in case you don't like ubuntu that much, use BOOTITNG to delete the ubuntu partitions. And then install windows

Comment: Sorry to bother again. But will using BOOTIT NG won't delete my other partition on which I have my data saved ?

Comment: The only thing I want to achieve is get back to Windows without loosing any of my data.

Comment: Don't worry about the othe partition. It's safe. If you're a bit scared of that happening, you can for a drive image using BOOTIT itself, so that if you delete the wrong partition and haven't formatted it yet (just deleted it), you can recover it. Although, Try not to delete that partition. Just in case, it seems complex, you have to delete the partitions with the filesystems roughly containing the words "linux" and "swap". Don't delete the NTFS one. And then, create a NTFS partition in the free space thus formed.

Comment: PS. Don't forget to mark this as solved, and vote my answer when solved. There are too many solved problems marked as unsolved anyways.